# How to check webhook call in Postman collection?

Tags: postman

I wanted to check webhook call in postman collection using post request with payload.

I dont know how to check the webhook call in postman. Can i get the ways to check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for example, your webhook URL is `https://www.somesite.com/call/this/webhook` and it expects POST request, then you can:

1. change the call method to `POST` (green in the attached screenshot)
2. use the URL for the webhook
3. inside 'Body' (orange) change to the type and format of payload you want (cyan and red in the screenshot)
4. add the payload you want (in this example - it's JSON)
5. click Send to check your webhook endpoint

[image]